# Delete selected file from a folder using checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

In this code every thing is right but,
I want that when i click on "Delete Selected Files" Button it delete the selected file using CheckBox that show on my GridView without any JavaScript,jquery and any plugin.
I don't know how i can do this.
I am using ASP.Net and C#.

Here is my ASPX Code :

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Full Name : " ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox1">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" /><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="Button1_Click"  style="margin-bottom:10px;" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Delete Selected Files" CausesValidation="false" style="margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:10px;" onclick="Button2_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Delete All" CausesValidation="false" style="margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:10px;" onclick="Button3_Click" />
    <div style="width:50%; overflow:auto; float:left;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Image Name" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Value" HeaderText="Image" ControlStyle-Height="100" ControlStyle-Width="100" />
        </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

C# Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void MsgBox(String MessageToDisplay)
    {
        Label lblForMsg = new Label();
        lblForMsg.Text = "<script language='javascript'>window.alert('" + MessageToDisplay + "')</script>";
        Page.Controls.Add(lblForMsg);
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime curr = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(curr, "India Standard Time");

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string time1 = INDIAN_ZONE.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_hhmmss");
                    string directoryPath = Server.MapPath(string.Format("./upload/" + TextBox1.Text));
                    if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }

                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                    fileName = time1 + fileName;
                    string path = "./upload/" + TextBox1.Text + "/";
                    hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path) + fileName);
                }
            }

            //GridView1 Bind with attach file
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + TextBox1.Text + "/"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                string fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                files.Add(new ListItem(fileName1, "~/upload/" + TextBox1.Text + "/" + fileName1));
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = files;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            string time1 = INDIAN_ZONE.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_hhmmss");
            string directoryPath = Server.MapPath(string.Format("./upload/" + TextBox1.Text));
            if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + TextBox1.Text + "/"));
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }

        string[] filePaths1 = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + TextBox1.Text + "/"));
        List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths1)
        {
            string fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            files.Add(new ListItem(fileName1, "~/upload/" + TextBox1.Text + "/" + fileName1));
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = files;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        MsgBox("Delete All Successfully");
    }
}
```

In this code every thing is right but,
I want that when i click on Delete Selected Files Button it delete the selected file using CheckBox.
I don't know how i can do this.
I am using ASP.Net and C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow di in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkId = (CheckBox)di.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (chkId != null)
        {
            if (chkId.Checked)
            {
                string fileName = di.Cells[1].Text;
                File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + TextBox1.Text + "/" + fileName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Button2_Click()`, go through the rows of grid view and check the check value of every checkbox. if it is checked, retrieve the file name present in the text box of that row. store it in array. and use this array finally to delete the files with filename stored in the array

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int nGridRowCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
     string[] filenames = new string[nGridRowCount];
     int index=0;
     for (int nSelect = 0; nSelect < nGridRowCount; nSelect++)
     {
         GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[nSelect];
         if (((CheckBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[1])).Checked)
         {
             filenames[index]=GridView1.DataKeys[nSelect]["Text"].ToString();
             // or you can do this, see which one works for you
             //filenames[index] = row.Cells[1].Text;
             index++;
         }
     }

    // Here will come the code to traverse
    // the filenames array and delete the files using file names stored in it
}
```